# Why my Multiple Thread stuck my UI and BackgroundWorker works

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have `Winforms` application that read several network folders and search for files inside this:

```
    public void test(List<string> folders, decimal numberOfFiles)
    {
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            foreach (string folder in folders)
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(folder))
                {
                    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.doc", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => new FileInfo(x).CreationTime).Take((int)numberOfFiles).ToList<string>();

                    if (files.Count != 0)
                    {
                        foreach (string file in files)
                        {
                            ProcessMyFile(file); // Check my file and if this file OK raised event the main UI and add this file into my `ListView`
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            (s3, e3) =>
            {
                 // Finish search all folders
            }
            );

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

This function received List of folders and search for x newest files, the result is small list (from every folder) that will check via another function (ProcessMyFile) and if the file OK raise event to my main UI and all this file in this way:

```
private AddFile(string file)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        // bla bla
    });
}
```

This works fine but because i have many files and because `test` checks every time ony one file i want to improve it to support `Multi Threading` sop i have this function that do the same:

```
public void test2(List<string> folders, decimal numberOfFiles)
{
    foreach (string folder in folders)
    {
        int numThreads = 10;
        ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        int toProcess = numThreads;
        // Start workers.
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
            new Thread(delegate()
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(folder))
                {
                    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.doc", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => new FileInfo(x).CreationTime).Take((int)numberOfFiles).ToList<string>();

                    if (files.Count != 0)
                    {
                        foreach (string file in files)
                        {
                            ProcessMyFile(file);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // If we're the last thread, signal
                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref toProcess) == 0)
                    resetEvent.Set();
            }).Start();
        }

        // Wait for workers.
        resetEvent.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

My problem here is that all my UI is struck although this function return files into `AddFile` function in the main UI and i cannot figure out why.

Comment: You do realize that you're executing 10 threads per folder in `test2()`, right?  I would've thought you'd run 1 thread per folder.  Also, for this type of work, I'd recommend the `System.Threading.ThreadPool` class instead of the `System.Threading.Thread` class, or more directly, use the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` class.  Finally, be sure to handle exceptions in your thread(s).  As you have it now, if one of the threads were to crash, `resetEvent` might never be signaled, and the function will never exit.

Answer (score 2):

After starting all threads, you block the UI thread with `resetEvent.WaitOne()`. So even though you invoke `// bla bla` on the UI thread it is not able to process it because it is blocked.

Instead of creating threads, you should look into `Task<T>`. It handles your background work in a much more sophisticated way, and it is able to automatically dispatch your continuation code to the UI thread for you.